# Delete row with foreign key constraints and no cascade deleting SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Trying to figure out how to delete a row in a SQL table that has multiple foreign keys pointing to it, and more keys pointing to those, etc, etc. Cascading Deletes aren't turned on (I have no control to turn them on), and I'm trying to avoid performing a delete on EVERY single row that is affected by this one delete.

So if I have table XXX, with columns YYY and ZZZ, where YYY is the primary key and ZZZ is a column that has multiple foreign keys pointing to it, how would I go about deleting a row based on the primary key value?

Syntax would be:
DELETE FROM XXX
WHERE YYY = some_value

Is this even possible (without performing a ton of individual deletes)? And if so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Either you need the foreign key constraints to cascade the delete (something I'm not terribly fond of, it makes it too easy for some application/ developer to think they can delete and re-insert some data rather than updating it in place without inadvertently causing all the child rows to be deleted) or you have to delete the child rows before you delete the parent.

Normally, if you want to delete the data from the child tables, it is easier to just manually write the various `DELETE` statements.  It would be possible to query the data dictionary (`dba_constraints`, `dba_cons_columns`, etc.) and dynamic SQL to walk all the constraints and generate the appropriate `DELETE` statements.  In the vast majority of cases, it wouldn't make sense to do that unless you're trying to generate `delete` statements for a large number of tables.

Answer (score 0):

How about turning off the foreign key constraint check?

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Then turning it on back when you delete the row?

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for correcting these for me, sorry  i am just starting learning this.:)